# Keras model_from_json() returning a string?

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the Keras `model_from_json()` function to load the structure of my model. I thought the return of this function was an instance of a Keras model, but it is returning a string for me?

My .json config file looks like this:

```
{"class_name": "MyModel", "config": {"hidden_layers": 2, "units": 64, "activation": "swish"}, "keras_version": "2.13.1", "backend": "tensorflow"}
```

When I call `model_from_json()` with this loaded json, it simply returns "MyModel", i.e the "class_name" in the config file.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: `model_from_json()` returns *A Keras model instance (uncompiled).* https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/model_from_json

Comment: @Goku but it is returning a string for me? Why is that?

Comment: please share your complete code.. also check for the version if it is `TensorFlow v2.14.0` ?

Comment: I am currently on v2.13.0 of TensorFlow

Comment: How exactly are you determining that it returns a string?

Comment: I can see it via the debugger, and it throws an attribute error when I call `load_weights()` on it, as it does not apply to a `str` object.

Comment: Please include a reproducible example and the output when executing it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing with `model_from_json()` is that it returns the class name mentioned in your JSON configuration, not an actual Keras model instance. In your case, it returns "MyModel" as specified in the "class_name" field. To address this, you need to create an instance of your custom model class and then load the model's weights separately using `load_weights()`.

You can try this approach:

```
with open('model_config.json', 'r') as json_file:   
    json_config = json_file.read()        

from MyModel import MyModel               
model = MyModel.from_config(json_config)  
model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')
```